# Matlab While statement

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I am using Matlab to develop my optimization project now. And I need use while loop to iterative .

But I am not know what wrong with my statement in while loop. It works find with another similar problem last time. 
My code like this :

```
while(norm(g_k)/(max(1,norm(v_k)) > eps && iter < iterMax)
rho = 0.00001;
v_k1 = v_k - rho*g_k
```

It always say:

> `Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.`

But I don't know what's wrong? I do not change something these days and I remember I can solve a similar problems some weeks ago
Thanks and BEST
Venus

Comment: Well, count your brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the error says, you brackets is not in pairs.
change

```
while(norm(g_k)/(max(1,norm(v_k)) > eps && iter < iterMax)
```

to

```
while(norm(g_k)/max(1,norm(v_k)) > eps && iter < iterMax)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing your parenthesis correctly see. You have one too many in the end or lack one in the beginning

```
while (norm(g_k)/(max(1,norm(v_k)) > eps && iter < iterMax
rho = 0.00001;
v_k1 = v_k - rho*g_k
```

or

```
while ( (norm(g_k)/(max(1,norm(v_k)) > eps && iter < iterMax )
rho = 0.00001;
v_k1 = v_k - rho*g_k
```